# Por qué utilizando Bigdecimal lo decimales de valor cero no los toma?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Manejo de BigDecimal en java 11

Recibo un String por ejemplo 5000.60 y lo paso por el siguiente método:

```
public BigDecimal stringToBigDecimalWithNull(String inputToTransform ) {
    return (inputToTransform == null || inputToTransform.equals("")) ? null : new BigDecimal(inputToTransform).setScale(2);
}
```

Lo que retorna el anterior medito lo fijo en un variable también con tipo de dato

```
BigdecimalcoverageDataDTO.setSumAssured(stringToBigDecimalWithNull(5000.60);
```

Ahora este dato viaja en un Json a otro servicio y Cuando verifico nuevamente el dato, veo que omitió el cero del numero 60, es decir 5000.6

¿Por que podría suceder esto?

De antemano muchas gracias por su colaboración. Saludos!!!!!!

Comment: Creo que es exactamente lo mismo que sucedería si pasas un float o un double. Los 0s a la derecha son irrelevantes y no se codifican de ninguna manera. Tendrás que pasarlos como string si no quieres perderlos. O pasar la cantidad de dígitos decimales para mostrarlo de la forma esperada cuando proceses el JSON recibido.

Comment: Le pasas un double al constructor de Big Decimal que en realidad recibe un String

Comment: Cuando lo mandes al JSON intenta usando [`toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--).

Comment: ¿No es mejor que el dato viaje como `String`, dado que los vas a enviar en un JSON y JSON no admite realmente `BigDecimal` y que en el destino lo conviertas a `BigDecimal`
?